# Same domain but still getting "Permission denied to access property 'document'"

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an app where I need to post to an iframe and get the contents. I have a `load` handler that gets the `innerHTML` from the frame, but the following throws an error:

```
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
```

I understand that this can happen to prevent XSS attacks, but I was under the impression this should only happen when the domains are different. I've checked and double-checked; the domain for the iframe matches the domain of the page, but I still can't get the frame contents.

Under what circumstances can a same-domain iframe access still cause this error?

Comment: Try debugging in Chrome. In my case, the error message was explicit enough to point me toward setting `document.domain` explicitly in the parent frame, and this turned out to be necessary even though the parent frame's default `document.domain` value should have been already correct!

Comment: and yes, both of my documents were on the same domain too

Comment: @BrettZamir If this is true, it should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging in Chrome. In my case, the error message was explicit enough to point me toward setting `document.domain` explicitly in the parent frame, and this turned out to be necessary even though the parent frame's default document.domain value should have been already correct!

I.e., I had to add this in the parent document:

```
document.domain = document.domain;
```